# is there a way to send data to prismic.io?

Tags: prismic.io

I need to push an object to prismic.io. For example, I want to send a simple object like a string to the CMS. 
I don't see any hints in the documentation that can help me achieve this. I'm using angular 7.
I already made my custom type, I can get the data I created with the CMS with prismatic predicates but can't send any data.

Answer (score 1):

no you can not do a write api. Its a read system, the only way to input is via their writing room or import (which is in writing room as well)

Comment: thank you for your reply you helped me a lot, i think i will use another CMS

Answer (score 1):

(full disclosure I'm working at Prismic ;) ) So the answer is: you can import data into Prismic. But it's not through a write API.

We want to introduce this at some point, but we also believe we can bring better solutions then just a write API for specific cases (like importing legacy content, connecting Prismic with an external data base, or with a translation service, etc.)
So our plan is to solve the most common use-cases of a "write API" in a more adapted/cleaner way, and then provide a write API afterwards.

Two solutions were already implemented:
1/ If you're looking to migrate existing content from another system into Prismic, you should check out our Import/Export feature: https://intercom.help/prismicio/import-export

2/ If you have content that lives in another system or in a custom API, it is possible to integrate this with Prismic using our Integration Fields feature: https://intercom.help/prismicio/integration-fields

3/ If what you want to do is not covered by these two solutions please let me know, that would be super helpful!

Comment: "in a more adapted way".  this answer is disingenuous.  if i have a custom api, the most adapted way to access it is the api itself.  integration fields do not sufficiently handle custom apis because you have to rely on a sync by prismic and your data can easily be stale. prismic is not meant for external custom data sources, only for external sources that are predefined and have native integrations eg shopify.